# Extract SVN url from WebSVN Project

Tags: svn, svn-checkout, websvn

I have this project http://mmcfe.mfis.net/ in WebSVN and i'd like to check out the trunk with the `svn checkout url` command. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You should ask your SVN server administrator.

Comment: ok, so generally there is no way to extract/find the SVN url from the WebSVN page?

Answer (score 0):

The only general answer is to ask your SVN admin or someone else in the know.  WebSVN can be configured in a variety of ways, and SVN repositories themselves can be available via four different protocols (svn, svn+ssh, http, https) each of which could have any paths.

Each repository is configured in WebSVN like so:

```
$config->addRepositorySubpath('NameToDisplay', 'internal url e.g. file:///c:/svn/proj', 'subpath', 'group', 'username', 'password', 'URL to display on web');
```

So my configurations are like this (note the nulls for parameters I don't use):

```
$config->addRepository('test123', 'file:///svn/test123', null, null, null, null, 'https://somehost.com/svn/test123');
```

That last parameter is not well documented (I think I found this out by reading [the source](http://websvn.tigris.org/source/browse/websvn/trunk/include/configclass.php?revision=1286&view=markup)) and is sometimes left out.  Without it, WebSVN will not provide a link for giving to SVN.

So there is no general heuristic you could use to convert the WebSVN URL to the SVN URL.  You may be able to guess, but I think asking someone is the best way to proceed.

Also, when you do contact the SVN admin, point out that the SVN URL should be included in the WebSVN configuration to prevent others from asking the same question.